# Help, how can I show that [G: M] is finite and prime.

Tags: group-theory

Let $M$ be a maximum subgroup of $G,$ that is, a proper subgroup of $G$ such that the only subgroups of $G$ that contain $M$ are $M$ and $G.$ It shows that if $M\underline{\lhd}G$ then $[G:M]$ is finite and prime.

Comment: Hi, could you explain a little bit about what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Consider $x$ not in $M$. Clearly, the image of $x$ in $M$ is non-trivial. Note then that $\langle M,x\rangle$ strictly contains $M$, so that$\langle M,x \rangle=G$ and $G/M=\langle xM\rangle$. This means $G/M$ is a cyclic group generated by any of its non-trivial elements- i.e., it is isomorphic to the integers modulo p, for some prime p. Then we have that $[G:M]$ is finite and prime.

Comment: Why is $G/M$ generated by $xM$?

Comment: Because if y is not in M then it can be written as a product of elements of M and of x.